# Skyrim crashes when I press continue or load

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Whenever I press continue or load Skyrim crashes to my desktop. It doesn't say anything it just crashes. I currently have no mods installed. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Are your savegames with mods which you uninstalled?

Comment: I haven't installed any mods.

Comment: Did it work before? If so, did you upgrade your OS/driver, swap a hardware etc between last time it worked and now?

Comment: It has worked before with minor errors occurring (I fixed them) There was no update. It just crashed and it stopped working. I press play on the launcher and it shows the Bethesda logo and then the Skyrim logo for 1 second and then it crashes

Comment: If I uncheck Dawnguard.esm, Dragonborn.esm and Hearthfires.esm it loads but I want to keep them so I can use shout and stuff what do I do

Comment: If you're still around: you could try reinstalling, or try loading a different saved game. Do you get a loading screen before it crashes?

Comment: Before reinstalling always verify the integrity of the game files first

Answer (score 1):

If you have the game on Steam, try to check cache integrity. 
Here is the detailed process:
Lauch Steam
From the Library section, right-click on the game and select Properties from the menu.
Select the Local files tab and click the Verify integrity of game cache... button.
Steam will verify the game's files - this process may take several minutes.

[Steam support source](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=2037-QEUH-3335)